SwiftUI: Pagination of posts in a ScrollView
In my SwiftUI project, I have a file called SearchViewModel where I have defined a function called fetchRandomPosts(). This function is responsible for randomly retrieving posts from Firestore. My problem lies in the way these posts load in the UI. Currently, all posts are displayed at once, which is not optimal for the app. My goal is to implement more efficient loading, starting the initial load at just 18 posts. Then as the user scrolls down the screen, 6 additional posts would load and so on.
SearchViewModel code:
@Published var posts: [PostModel] = []

// fetchRandomPosts() is to fetch posts randomly
func fetchRandomPosts() {
        db.collectionGroup("user_posts")
            .getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Error fetching documents: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                    return
                }
                
                let posts = documents.compactMap { document -> PostModel? in
                    do {
                        let post = try document.data(as: PostModel.self)
                        return post
                    } catch {
                        print("Error decoding post: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return nil
                    }
                }

                let randomPosts = posts.shuffled()

                self.posts = randomPosts
            }
    }


// dividePostsIntoGroups() sets the layout of the post rows in the UI view
func dividePostsIntoGroups() -> [[PostModel]] {
        var groups: [[PostModel]] = []
        var remainingPosts = posts
        
        while !remainingPosts.isEmpty {
            if remainingPosts.count >= 3 {
                groups.append(Array(remainingPosts.prefix(3)))
                remainingPosts = Array(remainingPosts.dropFirst(3))
            } else if remainingPosts.count == 2 {
                groups.append(Array(remainingPosts.prefix(2)))
                remainingPosts = []
            } else if remainingPosts.count == 1 {
                groups.append([remainingPosts.first!])
                remainingPosts = []
            }
        }
        
        return groups
    }

SearchView code:
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack {
        let groups = searchViewModel.dividePostsIntoGroups()
        
        ForEach(groups.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            let caseIndex = index % 5
            
            switch caseIndex {
            case 0:
                let post = groups[index].first
                let remainingPosts = Array(groups[index].dropFirst())
                
                HStack(spacing: 7) {
                    KFImage(URL(string: post?.postImage ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .modifier(ImagePostLargeModifier(post: post!))
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 7) {
                        ForEach(remainingPosts.prefix(2)) { post in
                            KFImage(URL(string: post.postImage))
                                .modifier(ImagePostMinModifier(post: post))
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            case 1, 2, 4:
                let posts = groups[index]
                
                HStack(spacing: 7) {
                    ForEach(posts) { post in
                        KFImage(URL(string: post.postImage))
                            .modifier(ImagePostMinModifier(post: post))
                    }
                }
                
            case 3:
                let post = groups[index].last
                let remainingPosts = Array(groups[index].dropLast())
                
                HStack(spacing: 7) {
                    VStack(spacing: 7) {
                        ForEach(remainingPosts.prefix(2)) { post in
                            KFImage(URL(string: post.postImage))
                                .modifier(ImagePostMinModifier(post: post))
                        }
                    }
                    
                    KFImage(URL(string: post?.postImage ?? ""))
                        .modifier(ImagePostLargeModifier(post: post!))
                }
                
            default:
                EmptyView()
            } 
        } 
        .animation(.spring(), value: searchViewModel.posts)
    }
}

I have looked for several solutions using a GeometryReader or a ScrollViewReader but so far I cannot find the correct way to carry out this task. As I said before, first bring 18 posts and when the user reaches the end of the screen then another six appear and so on (Basically how it works on a social network).

I think what are you looking for is infinite scrolling list. Here you have example: https://www.donnywals.com/implementing-an-infinite-scrolling-list-with-swiftui-and-combine/

Try removing view model that's what View struct is for

You first need to use LazyVStack instead of VStack inside the ScrollView.
Moreover, you'll need to implement something like this:
struct InfiniteListView: View {
    @State private var items: [Int] = Array(1...18)
    @State private var isFinished = false
    @State private var isLoading = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("Item \(item)")
                        .onAppear {
                            if item == items.last && !isFinished {
                                loadMoreItems()
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                if isLoading {
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func loadMoreItems() {
        isLoading = true
        // Simulate an asynchronous call
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            let moreItems = items.count + 1...items.count + 6
            items.append(contentsOf: moreItems)
            
            if items.count > 250 {
                isFinished = true
            }
            
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

